# Orchard v1.6: customising a theme

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

New to Orchard in that I just started to play around with it in the past few days. My question is about customising a theme (in this instance the Bootstrap one that can be installed from the gallery)

I tried to have a look and see if there was a non-source code way of doing it but was unable to find this way of doing it so I went spelunking through the theme folder and edited the Layout.cshtml file myself. Is this 'wrong' or is there another 'supported' way of doing it?

What I specifically wanted to do was to have the logo to the left and the menu to the right (see [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/bnpbndfx) for the OOB behaviour) and [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/zcgpfkzb) was the way that I achieved it.

I'm sure if there are any updates to this theme then the customisations will be overwritten hence the question about a supported way to achieve this.

Comment: This is how it's done.

Comment: Bon, merci beaucoup Bertrand. Si vous souhaitez mettre une réponse avec le même texte, je l'accepterai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how themes are customized.

Comment: It is a way yes, but I don't think modifying a downloaded theme is the recommened way to do what he's trying to accomplish.  He should be basing his new theme off of the one he downloaded right?  You obviously know alot more about Orchard than I do, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes it is. You can use a derived theme if you want, but it's frankly overkill. Themes are rarely if ever updated. I would never recommend modifying a module and not contributing the modifications, but for a theme it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to do is look up Derived themes, you should create a new theme based off the theme you're modifying, then you can just modify the parts you want, and if the original theme needs updates or w/e you can update it without overwritting all your changes.  I'm pretty sure this is the way you should be doing it.

This page should describe how that is done
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-the-default-theme

Comment: This is overkill in most cases. Themes are rarely if ever updated, and are perfectly fine as starting points.